# Use google bigquery to do cohort analysis

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say we have denormalized data: ( 100M of )

```
{
   user_cohort:      number, // weekly cohort
   user_action_date: number, // number of weeks after registration
   user_action:      string, // 
   ...
}
```

How can write a query that generates cohort report? ( assuming a weekly or monthly analysis )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great way to start with cohort analysis is to GROUP BY results according to a time bucket.

SELECT user_action_date FROM [table] WHERE user_action = 'something' and user_cohort = 4 GROUP BY user_action_date;

If you are using more granular timestamp data, there's a collection of that can extract the DAY, etc from a TIMESTAMP datatype, or else return an HOUR, DAY, MONTH etc from a POSIX timestamp in integer format.